# vectors within a vector and make comparison with each other.R

Tags: r

In R, vector myvector contains several vectors.How coule I compare all vectors within myvector with each other. I want to have the intersection between each two vectors within myvector.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
b <- c(1,3,5,7,8,9)
d <- c(1,2,5,7,9)
e <- c(1,3,4,8,0,10)
f <- c(2,3)
myvector <- c(a,b,d,e,f)
```

In short，how to simplify the modes as following.

```
intersect1 <- intersect(a,b)
intersect2 <- intersect(a,d)
intersect3 <- intersect(a,e)
intersect4 <- intersect(a,f)
intersect5 <- intersect(b,d)
...
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: So what's the end result you want? The numbers that occur in all vectors, or a list of intersections between pairs of vectors? If the latter, is it all possible pairs? Calling `c` on a bunch of vectors will just create one vector of them combined; I think you might want a list of those vectors instead

Comment: @camille my guess is that "myvector" is meant to be "mylist", then the question makes sense and there are a number of potential solutions (e.g. [link](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/jpmam1/R_scripts/blob/master/mylist_example.html)). I originally voted to close based on the lack of MRE, but the code was then added to the question, so I think it should be reopened.